# Are external email warnings effective?

Tags: email, phishing, end-user

Conceptually, "THIS EMAIL IS FROM AN EXTERNAL SENDER" warnings should be useful at preventing phishing or spoofing attacks.  If "your boss" asks you to buy a bunch of gift cards and you see that warning, maybe you catch it.

With so many legitimate external emails received, I'd imagine users may get a sort of [banner blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_blindness) and not even see them, reducing the effectiveness of the warning.

**Is there any data-backed research that shows the effectiveness of external sender warnings?**

Comment: I can certainly attest to the **harm** these warnings present: when you report such a marked-up message as a threat, we have to flag your submission as unusable because we don't want our systems to train on the warning text or link rewrites, especially if users don't report a balanced set of good vs bad emails.